# Nvidia/Elementary OS Juno suspend/resume fix

Tags: nvidia, gala, release-juno

Does anyone know if this will still work on Juno? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-nvidia-resume-bug-elementary-os-loki/amp/

I tried running gala —replace from the terminal a couple of times but it just freezes everything.

Are there any other solutions out there for refreshing the display after resume? (In case the title wasn’t clear, I have an Nvidia graphics card.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
cat > /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf << EOF
options nvidia_drm modeset=1
EOF

sudo update-initramfs -u
```

See also:
https://www.cmscritic.com/stop-screen-tearing-with-optimus-laptops-using-nvidia-drivers-in-linux/

https://wiki.debian.org/NVIDIA%20Optimus